# How can numpy uninstall error in python 3.8?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.8, pythonpath

I want to uninstall numpy in Python 3.8. I tried to that command "pip3 uninstall numpy",but this didn't work. I modified the PYTHONPATH in my  ~/.bashrc file and exported PYTHONPATH, but when I again install the nump, "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages(1.17.4)" output in console.

```
type here

~$ pip3 uninstall numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.24.1
Uninstalling numpy-1.24.1:
  Would remove:
    /home/efsun/.local/bin/f2py
    /home/efsun/.local/bin/f2py3
    /home/efsun/.local/bin/f2py3.8
    /home/efsun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy-1.24.1.dist-info/*
    /home/efsun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy.libs/libgfortran-040039e1.so.5.0.0
    /home/efsun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblas64_p-r0-15028c96.3.21.so
    /home/efsun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy.libs/libquadmath-96973f99.so.0.0.0
    /home/efsun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.24.1
~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.17.4)
~$ nano ~/.bashrc
~$ PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH: command not found
~$ nano ~/.bashrc
~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.17.4)
~$ nano ~/.bashrc
~$ source ~/.bashrc
~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.17.4)
~$ nano ~/.bashrc
~$ source ~/.bashrc
~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.17.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PYTHONPATH` will not affect package installation, and I would really advise against `PYTHONPATH` hacks in your bashrc, because you'll inevitably forget about them and wonder what the absolute heck is going on later.

`pip install numpy` is saying that because you already have a system-wide installation of NumPy 1.17.4 in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` (likely installed with `apt`), and just "I want numpy to be installed" is satisfied with that.

If you tried `pip install -U numpy`, it would attempt to upgrade Numpy to the latest version, and likely install it to your `.local` directory because it can't write to your `dist-packages`. But **don't do that** either – just [use a virtualenv and install the packages for your project there.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

In short,

```
$ python3.8 -m venv my-venv
$ source my-venv/bin/activate
$ pip install numpy
```